# How to pull a directory that is in .gitignore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-pull

In the `.gitignore` is a directory that I would need to pull on my localhost. I don't see this directory in the project structure o Github, but when I try to search it, I see this directory in the `.gitignore` file.

I pulled the project from Github on my localhost, but this directory is missing.
How can I get that directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the directory is listed in `.gitignore` then git will ignore that directory. That means it will not be added to commits and therefore not pushed to github und therefore you are not able to pull it.

Most of the time a directory is listed in `.gitignore` because the files inside that directory are generated automatically, e.g. when building the project.

Comment: There is any way to browse these files in Github?

Comment: They are not on github. Therefore there is also no way to browse them.